# What is the different between Tk() and Frame()?

Tags: python, tkinter

1. ```
   import tkinter as tk
   root = tk.Tk()
   root.mainloop()
   ```
2. ```
   import tkinter as tk
   root = tk.Tk()
   app = tk.Frame(root)
   app.mainloop()
   ```

After running each of these, the results seem the same.

Any advantage to using `tk.Frame()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Tk` creates the root window. Every tkinter application must have a root window. When you instantiate it you also create a tcl interpreter that is used by tkinter.

`Frame` is just a widget, designed to be a container for other widgets. It cannot act as a standalone window. An instance of `Frame` cannot exist without an instance of `Tk` -- if you don't explicitly create an instance of `Tk`, one will be created for you.

In your example there is no advantage to using frame because you a) don't make it visible with `pack`, `place`, or `grid`, and b) you don't put anything in it.

There are many advantages to using frames, but the main one is that it makes it easy to organize your widgets into logical groups.